# button link with jade in express

Tags: express, pug

```
 a.btn.btn-primary(href='/users/edit/#{user._id}') Manage
```

button link with jade
In my users.js

```
   router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {

  User.find({_id:req.param.id, function(err, user) {
    if(err)throw err;

       res.render('edit', {title:"edit",
       _id:user._id,
       name:user.name,
       username:user.username,
       role:user.role,
       email:user.email 
       });
       }})
  });
```

its not working how to fix it
 the issue is with in  href="/users/edit/#{user._id}"

Answer (score 1):

It should be `req.params` instead of `req.param`.

Everything else seems to be fine.

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {

  User.find({_id:req.params.id, function(err, user) {
    if(err)throw err;

       res.render('edit', {title:"edit",
       _id:user._id,
       name:user.name,
       username:user.username,
       role:user.role,
       email:user.email 
       });
       }})
  });
```